# After updating firebase the mat-dialog is reopened

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-material

In my application I use a form on a mat-dialog to update a table on firebase. The dialog is opened when a button is clicked. When the update button on the dialog's form is clicked I call a function from a service that updates the data on firebase and the dialog closes. But after the dialog is closed it is reopened without any user interaction or code call.

Here is the code in the dialog I use to update firebase:

```
    this.firebaseService.update(key, data).subscribe(res => {

      // firebase is updated
      if (res) {

        let message = this.translate.instant("UPDATE");
        let title = this.translate.instant("SUCCESS");

        this.snackBar.open(message, title, {
          duration: 2500,
          verticalPosition: 'top',
          panelClass: 'mat-simple-snackbar-success'
        });

        this.dialogRef.close();
      }
    });
```

Has anybody faced this issue?

Comment: can you please create a stackblitz repro?

Comment: @Siddharth Pal the form contains realtime sensitive data and I cannot create a repro...

Comment: maybe a propagation problem? Have you tried to call $event.stopPropagation(); ?

Comment: @Kalamarico thanks for the hint I will check this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the code that open the snackBar outside the subscribe block